# I'm trying to get the informations with the v-for loop, but I couldn't get the data in the generalRights part. What did I do wrong?

Tags: vue.js

```
     <div id="ags">
      <div
        class="cardgs"
        v-for="(informations, detailedinformations) in subdetailedinformations"
        :key="detailedinformations"
      >
        <b-card
          :title="informations.memberType"
          :img-src="informations.img"
          img-alt="Image"
          img-top
          tag="article"
          img-width="100%"
          img-height="100%"
        >
          <b-card-text class="sct">
            <p class="bb">
              {{ informations.generalRights }}
            </p>
          </b-card-text>
          <b-button href="./readySales/contentwritingrs" variant="primary">
            {{ subscribe }}</b-button
          >
        </b-card>
      </div>
    </div>

 data: function () {
    return {
      subscriptions: "Abonelikler",
      subscriptionPackages:
        "Fiyuva'da özel ayrıcalıklara sahip olmak için; sizlere sunduğumuz abonelik paketlerine göz atın!",
      bronzeMember: "Bronz Üye",
      silverMember: "Gümüş Üye",
      goldMember: "Altın Üye",
      platinMember: "Platin Üye",
      subdetailedinformations: [
        {
          memberType: "Bronz Üye",
          img: require("./images/writer.jpg"),
          generalRights: [
            { rights: " 1- Müşteri Desteği" },
            { rights: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
            { rights: " 3- Aylık 3 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 4- 1 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 5- 1 Revizyon Hakkı" },
          ],
        },
        {
          memberType: "Gümüş Üye",
          img: require("./images/analysis.jpg"),
          generalRights: [
            { rights: " 1- Müşteri Desteğinde Öncelik" },
            { rights: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
            { rights: " 3- Aylık 10 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 4- 2 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 5- 2 Revizyon Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 6- Günlük reklam ücretinde %5 indirim" },
          ],
        },

        {
          memberType: "Altın Üye",
          img: require("./images/design.jpg"),
          generalRights: [
            { rights: " 1- VİP Müşteri Desteği" },
            { rights: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
            { rights: " 3- Aylık 15 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 4- 3 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            { rights: " 5- 3 Revizyon Hakkı" },
            {
              rights: " 6- Günlük ve haftalık reklam ücretinde %5 indirim",
            },
          ],
        },

        {
          memberType: "Platin Üye",
          img: require("./images/consultancy.jpg"),
          generalRights: [
            { rights: " 1- VİP Müşteri Desteğinde Öncelik" },
            { rights: " 2- Süper Hızlı Teslimat" },
            { rights: " 3- Aylık 25 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
            {
              rights: " 4- Tüm Kategorilerde Hazır Satış Hakkı",
            },
            { rights: " 5- 4 Revizyon Hakkı" },
            {
              rights:
                " 6- Günlük, haftalık ve aylık reklam ücretinde %5 indirim",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      bronzeSubscription: [
        { rightsofBronzeMembers: " 1- Müşteri Desteği" },
        { rightsofBronzeMembers: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
        { rightsofBronzeMembers: " 3- Aylık 3 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofBronzeMembers: " 4- 1 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofBronzeMembers: " 5- 1 Revizyon Hakkı" },
      ],
      silverSubscription: [
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 1- Müşteri Desteğinde Öncelik" },
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 3- Aylık 10 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 4- 2 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 5- 2 Revizyon Hakkı" },
        { rightsofSilverMembers: " 6- Günlük reklam ücretinde %5 indirim" },
      ],
      goldSubscription: [
        { rightsofGoldMembers: " 1- VİP Müşteri Desteği" },
        { rightsofGoldMembers: " 2- Hızlı Teslimat" },
        { rightsofGoldMembers: " 3- Aylık 15 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofGoldMembers: " 4- 3 Kategoride Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofGoldMembers: " 5- 3 Revizyon Hakkı" },
        {
          rightsofGoldMembers:
            " 6- Günlük ve haftalık reklam ücretinde %5 indirim",
        },
      ],
      platinumSubscription: [
        { rightsofPlatinumMembers: " 1- VİP Müşteri Desteğinde Öncelik" },
        { rightsofPlatinumMembers: " 2- Süper Hızlı Teslimat" },
        { rightsofPlatinumMembers: " 3- Aylık 25 Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofPlatinumMembers: " 4- Tüm Kategorilerde Hazır Satış Hakkı" },
        { rightsofPlatinumMembers: " 5- 4 Revizyon Hakkı" },
        {
          rightsofPlatinumMembers:
            " 6- Günlük, haftalık ve aylık reklam ücretinde %5 indirim",
        },
      ]
      subscribe: "Abone Ol",
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't access `generalRights` because it's an array and not an object.

you can write another `v-for` to access the items in the array:

```
<template v-for="right in informations.generalRights">
  <p class="bb">
    {{ right.rights }}
  </p>
</template>
```

Comment: There is an error in the values that come after doing this.

The values come as follows.

{ "rights": " 1- Customer Support" }

But I want it this way

1- Customer Support"

Is this possible?